# Create a trigger to update a table based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Please I need your help. I have been working on a trigger statement and it seem not to be working.

I need help on writing a trigger to update a table called **`membership`** when a column on another table called **`serialcode`** is updated.

**DETAILS:** I have two tables called `membership` and `serialcode`. The membership table has the following columns

```
id    fullname    email    date   state    sn
```

and the serialcode table has only

```
id     sn
```

I want the **sn** in membership to be updated with the value of **sn** in serialcode is updated where the **id** in **membership** table is same as the **id** in **serialcode** table.

Here is what I have been able to write below

```
CREATE TRIGGER MembershipSerialCode
BEFORE UPDATE ON serialcode
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
if :new.sn != :old.sn
then
   UPDATE membership m
   set membership.sn = :new.sn
   where m.id = :new.id;
end if;
END;
```

Thank you.

Mike

Comment: What is wrong with that?  It looks good to me.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go with triggers at all? They're evil, it's usually better to update the tables yourself where needed. That said, if you need a trigger, could the issue be on your "where" clause.. should that be :old.id? Or, should it be m.sn = :old.sn?

Comment: I really done know where the fault is from. I am open to other options instead triggers. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this one and let me know if you have luck on implementing it?

```
CREATE Trigger TriggerName                         
 ON SerialNumberTable FOR UPDATE 

AS                         

IF (Update(sn)) -- This is the column on SerialCodeTable that will be updated first                     
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (Select i.id                      
    FROM Deleted d INNER JOIN Inserted i                      
 ON d.id = i.id
 AND d.sn <> i.sn)
 BEGIN
    UPDATE MembershipTable SET MembershipTable.sn = i.sn 
            FROM Inserted i 
            WHERE MembershipTable.id = i.id
 END
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Please a quick one: In which of the tables; membership or serialcode should I insert the trigger?

Comment: The trigger should be on the SerialCode table since its the one that will first be updated. Apologies for late response...

Comment: It didnt work. Did you try it? If yes, can you send me the print screen please